# Cannot run pyLDAvis. Getting Error : ImportError: cannot import name PCoA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim, skbio

I have created LDA model using gensim. Now, I wanted to visualise it using pyLDAvis library but getting :

```
ImportError: cannot import name PCoA
```

Can anyone help me with this or suggest some alternatives.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the scikit-bio python package. It must be < than 0.4.x. From the version 0.4.x, the method has a different name.

You have to install the right version in the following way:

> sudo pip install scikit-bio==0.2.X

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The name of this function changed from the 0.2.x (alpha) to 0.4.x (beta) branch of scikit-bio. You can either use the function with the old name by installing scikit-bio 0.2.3, or modify your code to use the new function name. I recommend the latter as this interface is stabilizing, so making the change now will allow you to continue to get access to the latest features.

There are two pieces involved in updating your `PCoA` call for 0.4.1. You'll need to adapt your import and function calls to use the new name (`pcoa` - all lowercase now, see [changelog note on this here](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#backward-incompatible-changes-experimental)), and then change how you interact with the results, as the `OrdinationResults` object has been improved between these releases. First, your import should now look like:

```
from skbio.stats.ordination import pcoa
```

Then, you can review the [changelog description of what's changed with the `OrdinationResults` object here](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#backward-incompatible-changes-experimental).

If you do just want to stick with 0.2.3, either of the following should work for installation:

```
pip install scikit-bio==0.2.3
conda install scikit-bio==0.2.3
```

On a related note, see our [API stability docs](http://scikit-bio.org/docs/0.4.0/user/api_stability.html) to see how you can learn about what features are stable/experimental/deprecated in scikit-bio.